# Mixed Feelings - What am I

Tags: riddle, word

> People have mixed feelings about me
>
> If people take good care of themselves, I will go up
>
> I can change people's appearances, view of the world and understanding
>
> Some people may want to flaunt me, however, many try to hide me
>
> But no matter what you do, I will show
>
> People try to defy me, but they won't succeed
>
> And no matter what, I will not go down
>
> What am I?

Hope you like it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should fit the riddle:

> Age

**Explanation :**

People have mixed feelings about me

> Some people embraces age (eg kids wanting to grow up) while some people resist.

If people take good care of themselves, I will go up

> If people remain healthy and free from accidents, they will grow up, and since their **age** increases

I can change people's appearances, view of the world and understanding

> With **age** comes change in appearances, perspective and wisdom

Some people may want to flaunt me, however, many try to hide me

> Kids may want to flaunt their advanced age as compared to other children. Some people also feel that age is a sign of their superiority. While there are some who are afraid to show their age.

But no matter what you do, I will show
People try to defy me, but they won't succeed

> Despite make-up/plastic surgery/botox/good maintenance, age will still show in the physical body.

And no matter what, I will not go down

> Age cannot decrease. Probably an apt news to show here will be [this](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/dec/03/dutch-court-rejects-emile-ratelband-request-20-years-younger)